# Clonezilla automated backup

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I'm looking for a solution to backup a Ubuntu server.
I've tried Acronis 12.5 backups where I installed an agent on Ubuntu and backups were managed in the cloud. This didn't work out well. Couldn't recover, even after hours of working with their support.
Then I tried Clonezilla, this worked perfectly! I created an image on a USB drive and restored it to another PC and it worked. The only drawback is that I need to shut the server down for that.
Is there any way to automate this?
I prefer not having to reboot the server. I could write a script to stop the postgres DB etc while the backup is running. I think it is necessary to shut down to make a backup.
Would there be a way to write a script to shutdown the PC, start Clonezilla from USB or network?, create the backup on a NAS and boot back into Ubuntu?
When I look this up I only find tutorials on how to backup with the live USB disk.